# xlwings (0.10.0) Automation error while importing UDF

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

i am using xlwings for the first time, i created a file using the "xlwings quickstart" command and added the following function in the python file

```
    @xlw.func
    def add(x,y):
    return 2 * (x+y)
```

when i try to import this udf into the excel file, i get a Runtime `error 440 Automation error`

[image: Automation Error]

[image: VBA Line in error]

I am using `Python 3.5.2`, my excel is 32 bit pro plus.

Answer (score 1):

I solved same problem with:
- under Excel, go to File/Options/Trust Center/Trust Center Settings
- in Macro Settings make sure "Trust access to the VBA porject object model" is checked